# dropzone.js `maxfilesexceeded` event is not getting fired. When adding files programatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropzone.js, dropzone, vue-dropzone

I am using dropzone in my vuejs project. I have set `maxFiles: 1` in my dropzone options.

Now I have to show existing file from server in dropzone so i am using this code to add existing file in my dropzone.

```
let mockFile = { name: 'Filename', size: file.size };
myDropzone.emit('addedfile', mockFile);
myDropzone.emit('thumbnail', mockFile, file.dataURL);
myDropzone.emit('success', mockFile);
myDropzone.emit('complete', mockFile);
myDropzone.files.push(file);
```

This code is working fine and file is getting added in the dropzone. However when i add more files(manually) to that dropzone the `maxfilesexceeded` event is not getting fired.

Note: if i add files manually instead of programatically then it is firing `maxfilesexceeded` event.

Answer (score 0):

use this after push Every item to files list:

```
myDropzone._updateMaxFilesReachedClass();
```

Comment: Please add some description about your solution, which makes it easier for author to understand your solution.